# Composer autoload with our naming convention

Tags: composer-php, autoload, autoloader

Our naming convention for classes has been name_class.php.  Is there a way to append _class in the class file name look up?  I changed the loadClass function in the ClassLoader.php file to get it to work but a composer install overwrites my change.

Answer (score 1):

No, composer does only support PSR-0, PSR-4 and for all other schemes the classmap.

If your name scheme does not conform to PSR-0 at least, all you can do is to use the classmap and always create a classmap update if you add a new class. I'd highly recommend to create new classes conforming to PSR-4 or PSR-0 standard to get rid of this need when using Composer. The old classes might still be located somewhere and loaded via classmap if you do not want to rename the files.

You can however run the composer autoloader parallel to your own. Then you are still responsible for your own classes, but use Composer for all the libraries.